# How to generate table script with data using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

i want to create script for the table with data,i know, how to generate script of table using c#,but i can't get any coding of script of table with data

```
 StringCollection tableScripts = myTable.Script(scriptOptionsForDependendencies);
        foreach (string script in tableScripts)
            Console.WriteLine(script);
```

this ways using

Comment: what is myTable?

Comment: Table myTable = myAdventureWorks.Tables["<table name>"];

        ScriptingOptions scriptOptionsForDependendencies = new ScriptingOptions();
        scriptOptionsForDependendencies.WithDependencies = true;
        scriptOptionsForDependendencies.DriAll = true;
        string name = myTable.Name;
         scriptOptionsForDependendencies.FileName = @"I:\capmanversion\ijob\" + name + ".sql";
               StringCollection tableScripts = myTable.Script();
        foreach (string script in tableScripts)
            Console.WriteLine(script);

Answer (score 0):

Set `scriptOptionsForDependendencies.ScriptData = true`. This looks like it will do the work for you.

Put this as `scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;`

[ScriptingOptions sql smo does not support scripting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003017/scriptingoptions-sql-smo-does-not-support-scripting-data)

Comment: i check this thing but showing error  This method does not support scripting data.