# c# generating INSERT script with data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I try to generate a script which is contains datas in INSERT script forms,
I try to use a reference (see below) to do it

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

with this code draft

```
Server serv = new Server(db);
Database simba = serv.Databases[dbname];
string script = "";

ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions()
{
    ScriptData = true,
    ScriptSchema = false,
    ScriptDrops = false
};

foreach (Table tb in simba.Tables)
{
    if (tables.Contains(tb.Name))
    {
        var sc = tb.Script(so);
        foreach (var s in sc)
            script += s;

    }
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        foreach (string tab in tables)
        writer.WriteLine(script);
    }
}
```

but this code get an error on

```
var sc = tb.Script(so);
```

which is

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException

thanks for all reply

Comment: What is the rest of the exception detail?

Comment: Show example of the script you're running

Comment: @bugfinder I think they are trying to generate a string with scripts, not run them. Have you tried explicitly typing the string?

Comment: @Crowcoder Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Cette méthode ne prend pas en charge le script de données.
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ScriptImpl(ScriptingOptions so)
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableViewTableTypeBase.Script(ScriptingOptions scriptingOptions)
   à generateScriptSQL.Program.Main(String[] args) dans c:\users\cad\Source\Repos\generateScriptSQL\generateScriptSQL\Program.cs:ligne 84

Comment: @JacobH do you mean without generating? i can use the publisher wizard directly on mssql but i try to automatisate my task

Comment: No I meant strictly typing instead of implicit `var`. Not sure if that's the issue. Where is `tables` coming from?

Comment: what's wrong in my question? why i get a bad point??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ScriptingOptions sql smo does not support scripting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003017/scriptingoptions-sql-smo-does-not-support-scripting-data)

Comment: Indent the code - it is hard to read.  { } do not match.  You can pull `ScriptingOptions so` out of the loop.    But I don't know why it is failing.

Comment: same error, tables is a list of what i want to generate

Answer (score 4):

I have this code and it is working fine try to use it

```
var report   = string.Empty;
var fileName = Server.MapPath(Constants.BACKUP_FILE_NAME);

var server      = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(Constants.BACKUP_CONNECTION_STRING)));
var options     = new ScriptingOptions();
var databases   = server.Databases[Constants.BACKUP_DATABASE_NAME];                    

options.FileName                = fileName;
options.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;
options.WithDependencies        = true;
options.IncludeHeaders          = true;
options.ScriptDrops             = false;
options.AppendToFile            = true;
options.ScriptSchema            = true;
options.ScriptData              = true;
options.Indexes                 = true;

report = "<h4>Table Scripts</h4>";
foreach (var table in Constants.BACKUP_TABLES)
{
    databases.Tables[table, Constants.BACKUP_SCHEMA_NAME].EnumScript(options);                        
    report += "Script Generated: " + table + "<br>";
}
```

The "Constants" is my class to hold the constant values like file name, db etc and I am generating script for limited tables so for that reason not doing "simba.Tables" like you have done in your code; you can surely do that if you want every table scripts to be generated. So this code generates script and store it to specified file.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Zaki Mohammed,

Your code helped me a lot,

I just modify a bit for my case and it works perfectly,

```
            Server serv = new Server(db);
            Database simba = serv.Databases[dbname];
            Scripter scripter = new Scripter(serv);
            scripter.Options.FileName = "InsertIntoScript.sql";
            scripter.Options.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;
            scripter.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = true;
            scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = false;
            scripter.Options.AppendToFile = true;
            scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = false;
            scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
            scripter.Options.Indexes = false;

            string script = "";
            foreach (Table tb in simba.Tables)
            {
                if (tables.Contains(tb.Name))
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> sc = scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn });
                    foreach (var s in sc)
                        script += s;
                }
            }
```

Comment: NOTE:  the script += stuff can be very slow with large data.
Using the following got me from over three minutes to about 7 seconds.

StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

...

script.Append(s);

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serverName = @"xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS";
        string databaseName = "databaseName";
        string outputPath = "C:\\ScriptFile1.sql";
        string connectionString = $"Server={serverName};Database={databaseName};Integrated Security=true;";

        try
        {
            GenerateInsertScript(connectionString, outputPath);
            Console.WriteLine($"Insert script generated successfully: {outputPath}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    static void GenerateInsertScript(string connectionString, string outputPath)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        connection.Open();

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string tableName = reader.GetString(0);
                GenerateInsertStatements(connection, tableName, writer);
            }
        }
    }
    static void GenerateInsertStatements(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}", connection);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();



        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                columns.Append($"{dataReader.GetName(i)}, ");
                values.Append($"@{dataReader.GetName(i)}, ");
            }

            columns.Length -= 2; // Remove the trailing comma and space
            values.Length -= 2; // Remove the trailing comma and space


            writer.WriteLine($"-- Insert statements for {tableName}");
            writer.WriteLine($"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({columns.ToString()}) VALUES");

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                writer.Write("(");
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if (dataReader.FieldCount - 1 == i)
                    {
                        writer.Write($"'{EscapeSqlString(dataReader[i].ToString())}' ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.Write($"'{EscapeSqlString(dataReader[i].ToString())}', ");
                    }
                }

                writer.WriteLine("),");
            }

        }
        writer.WriteLine();

    }
    static string EscapeSqlString(string input)
    {
        // Implement any necessary SQL string escaping logic here
        return input.Replace("'", "''");
    }
```